# Viscous drag proportional to $r$ or $r^3$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

When a spherical object is falling at terminal velocity through a fluid: $W=U+F$, where $W$ is weight, $U$ is upthrust and $F$ is viscous drag. Rewriting, using Stoke's Law, we get:
$$\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\rho_{object}.g=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\rho_{fluid}.g+6\pi r\eta v_t$$
$$6\eta v_t= \frac{4}{3} r^2\rho_{object}.g - \frac{4}{3} r^2\rho_{fluid}.g$$
$$v_t = \frac{2r^2(\rho_{object}-\rho_{fluid}).g}{9\eta},$$

where $r$ is the radius of the object, $\rho$ is density, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration, $\eta$ is the viscosity coefficient, and $v_t$ is the terminal velocity of the object.

So $v_t$ varies proportionally to $r^2$.

However, clearly upthrust varies proportionally to $r^3$. This implies that $F$ varies proportionally to $r$ so that $v_t$ can be proportional to $r^2$. But $F=6\pi r \eta v_t$, so as we increase $r$, $v_t$ increases quadratically, meaning that $F$ must increase cubically.

This seems to be a contradiction - $v_t$ is proportional to $r^2$ so $F$ is proportional to $r$, but also $F$ is proportional to $r^3$.

So where is my reasoning wrong, and does $F$ vary proportionally to $r$ or $r^3$?

**EDIT:**

I found this quote on the Wikipedia page for Stokes' law:

> Note that since buoyant force increases as $R^3$ and Stokes drag increases as $R$, the terminal velocity increases as $R^2$ and thus varies greatly with particle size as shown below.

Comment: "upthrust varies proportionally to r3. This implies that F varies proportionally to r" No this implies that F must vary cubically because F (and not $v_tF$) has to balance against W and U

Comment: Right, I thought that was probably the mistake. Does that mean that my exam mark scheme, which says that $F$ varies proportionally to $r$, is wrong?

Comment: The exact words of the mark scheme are: "Viscous drag varies in proportion to radius (or area in proportion to radius
squared), but weight varies in proportion to radius cubed,
(terminal) velocity proportional to radius squared". Is this wrong??

Comment: @Azad  See my edit

Comment: probably what the exam meant was direct dependence. i.e at fixed velocity not the terminal velocity. if an object of twice the radius moves at the same velocity feels twice the force.

Comment: @Azad  Right, ok, thanks. I think you are right - $F$ increases as $r$ from the equation, so $v_t$ must increase as $r^2$ to balance upthrust and weight. I think that is what it was looking for.